# Setting Capistrano current path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I need to override default Capistrano current path. I want to deploy to `/var/www/apps/myapp`
and then get current symlink set at `/var/www/mysite.com` instead of default `/var/www/apps/myapp/current`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the following in your deploy.rb:

```
set :current_path, '/var/www/mysite.com'
```

That might trip up plugins, script or other parts of capistrano that assume a default layout.

A safer solution would be to simply symlink `/var/www/mysite.com` to `/var/www/apps/myapp/current`

Comment: Silly me. I've overlooked the most straightforward solution. Thanks!